# pattern match with 2 middle number in java

Tags: java

I want third pattern ([0-9]{2}) should less than 10 or 10. I've also tried with [1-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-0] pattern instead of [0-9]{2} but unable to get the solution. I want result in following format: 012 550 10 0123456 01.

```
public static void main(String args[]){         
            System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[0-9]{3}[550]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{6}[01]{2}", "8035501002499901")); 
}
```

Comment: So you want to either match 0-9 or 10? Then that part of the pattern would be `(?:[0-9]|10)`, as easy as that.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of pattern do you need. Can you be a bit more precise and give more examples ?

Comment: It seems you've confused some things about regex so you might want to refer to some tutorial first. As an example `[550]{3}` would not only match 550 but also 000, 555, etc. (and in case you want that just `[05]{3}` would be sufficient).

Comment: Tomas, I'm new in java regex, i just want to validate one number. number format is following :-first 3 digit

Comment: Well, if you want to use regex you should understand them (at least the basics), as is true with every piece of technology.

Comment: [0-9]{3}[550]{3}((0[0-9])|10)[0-9]{6}[01]{2} will work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it seems as if the pattern you want is this:

- any 3 digits (`[0-9]{3}`)
- 550 fixed (`550`) - note that `[550]{3}` would mean any sequence of 3 digits that are either 5 or 0, e.g. 005, 050, 555, etc.
- 2 digits which either should be 0x or 10 (`(?:0[0-9]|10)`)
- any 6 digits (`[0-9]{6}`)
- 01 fixed  (`01`) - `[01]{2}` would mean any sequence of 2 digits that are either 0 or 1, e.g. 00, 01, 10 and 11 all would match

Thus the regex you'd need would be:

```
[0-9]{3}550(?:0[0-9]|10)[0-9]{6}01
```

Comment: i just want to validate one number. number format is following :-first 3 digit – 0-9 , sec 550 is fixed, third number should 10 or less than 10 it might be 01,02---10 , forth 6 digit  0-9, and last should 01 is fixed eg 0125500101236501

Comment: @pacificstar well, have a look at the answer, seems I got your requirments right.